# StorageBucket support in Ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am on `GKE 1.18.17-gke.700`

Per reference it seems it is supported in that api reference:
[image]

But I am getting this error:

```sh
The Ingress "sample-ingress" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.resource: Forbidden: not supported; only service backends are supported in this version
```

Sample config looks like this:

```yaml
...
...
...
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "example.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/hello"
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              resource:
                kind: StorageBucket
                name: hello-bucket
          - path:
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no possibility to set the `GKE Ingress` to send the request to the `GCS` bucket. There is a feature request created to address it (you can follow it for future updates):

- *[Issuetracker.google.com: Issues: GKE Ingress with a GCS Bucket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182815525?pli=1)*

This is the information outside of the issue you are experiencing which I will address below.

---

You are unable to create an `Ingress` resource:

```
The Ingress "sample-ingress" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.resource: Forbidden: not supported; only service backends are supported in this version
```

because of the following message:

```
Forbidden: not supported; only service backends are supported in this version
```

In short, your Kubernetes API is rejecting this manifest as it supports only `Service` backend in this particular version.

---

`Ingress` had some major changes in version `1.19` (change from `Beta` to `GA` (`General Availability`):

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: CHANGELOG-1.19: Ingress graduates to general availability](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.19.md#ingress-graduates-to-general-availability)*

For the: `spec.rules.http.paths.backend.`**`resource`** to be accepted by `API` you will need to **update your `GKE` cluster to version `1.19` (or newer).** (this still won't be working)

> A side note!
>
> If you've decided to upgrade your `GKE` cluster to version `1.19` and newer, please use:
>
> - `networking.k8s.io/v1`
> - instead of `networking.k8s.io/v1beta` (deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+)

---

I encourage you to check the additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Release notes: 1.19 GA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#119_ga)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)*

Comment: I was looking at this doc - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#resource-backend and was not sure if it was in `GKE 1.18`